# UIApplicationState returning Inactive despite app in foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Shortly after launch, my app spins of a separate thread. This thread checks whether or not the app is in the background or active, as it can be called from either. However, when the app is explicitly launched, [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState returns UIApplicationStateInactive. I would expect it to return UIApplicationStateActive. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Seems I have figured it out, but correct me if I am wrong. Anything called from applicationDidFinishLaunching will return inactive. applicationDidFinishLaunching has to return YES before the state changes from Inactive to Active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is stated in the apple documentation:

> You should use this method to initialize your application and prepare it for running. It is called after your application has been launched and its main nib file has been loaded. **At the time this method is called, your application is in the inactive state**. At some point after this method returns, **a subsequent delegate method is called to move your application to the active (foreground) state or the background state**.

Comment: this sucks, then how to detect if my in foreground?